# Переписать ключи в массиве

Tags: php

После обработки массива `array_unique();` (уничтожает дубликаты значений) в массиве остаются пропущенные ключи: `1 3 4 5 8`
Есть ли функция чтобы переписать ключи от 0 и до кол-ва элементов в массиве?

Comment: А ключи всегда числа? Или массив может быть ассоциированным? Т.е. использование [array_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) вас устроит или надо будет сохранять так же и ассоциативные ключи?

Comment: @BOPOH, отвечайте в виде ответа, а не комментария :Р

Comment: @BOPOH ключи - числа, всегда

Comment: @Visman, это был коммент, т.к. если у ТС ключи были бы не всегда числовые, то надо было бы использовать другой подход

Comment: @BOPOH ставьте ответом

Comment: @BOPOH, тут "Есть ли функция чтобы переписать ключи от 0 и до кол-ва элементов в массиве?" ясно написано ;)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте: [array_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php). 
Пример:

```
<?php
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

Ответ:

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```